# Finding a Literal control from master page inside of a user control getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I have a master page which loads a user control to a placeholder

Code example

```
placeHolderNav.Controls.Clear()
Dim ucATG As UserControl = DirectCast(LoadControl("/main/navigation.ascx"), UserControl)
ucATG.ID() = "lookJS"
placeHolderNav.Controls.Add(ucATG)
```

Inside that navigation.ascx control there is a literal with ID `litShowWork`. The child page is `getwork.aspx`, which has a method called that insert into that literal from a child page

code sample

```
Dim litOmniture As Literal = DirectCast(Me.Master.FindControl("lookJS").FindControl("litShowWork"), Literal)

If Not litOmniture Is Nothing Then
    litShowWork.Text &= "hello"
End If
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: would be nice however i'm working with legacy code

Answer (score 0):

I would expose a public property in your masterpage e.g. `ShowWorkText` as `String`. This property sets (or reads) the Literal's `Text`. It searches the control in the `Placeholder` that is accessible directly. Then your code is more readable and more maintainable. It's also safer if you decide to replace the `Literal` with a `TextBox` for example. You have to cast the page's `Master` property to the actual type of your master to access that property.

Since the literal is in a `UserControl` you should use the same approach to expose the property there. Then the master accesses it instead of the page.

In the master (of type `Site`):

```
Public Property ShowWorkText As String
    Get
        Dim navigationControl As Navigation = Me.placeHolderNav.Controls.OfType(Of Navigation)().FirstOrDefault()
        If navigationControl IsNot Nothing Then
            Return navigationControl.ShowWorkText
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Dim navigationControl As Navigation = Me.placeHolderNav.Controls.OfType(Of Navigation)().FirstOrDefault()
        If navigationControl IsNot Nothing Then
            navigationControl.ShowWorkText = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

in the UserControl (of type `Navigation`, `LiteralShowWork` is the litaral):

```
Public Class Navigation
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Property ShowWorkText As String
        Get
            Return LiteralShowWork.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            LiteralShowWork.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

in the page that want to set the text (as mentioned `Site` is the type of the master):

```
Dim site As Site = TryCast(Me.Master, Site)
If site IsNot Nothing Then
    site.ShowWorkText = "hello"
End If
```

Comment: that would work but my hands are tied at this moment since every other page use the same thing. I have to work with what i got :(.